# React Native (Android) not sensing my <TouchableOpacity/> component absolute positioned above a <TextInput/>

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have created a custom 'Autocomplete' component that has a TextInput and an absolute positioned dropdown that triggers when you type certain characters in it. In the dropdown, there are list items that are touchable and should trigger a function to fill the TextInput when pressed on.

On the screen component, I have included this 'Autocomplete' component four times. When I trigger the dropdown and try pressing on one of those list items within it, its like it ignores the dropdown completely and just lets me focus into the next 'Autocomplete' component's TextInput that is actually layered below the dropdown.

My code works perfectly fine on iOS devices but on Android, it has presented problems.

[View the gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNrHl.gif)

Link to the Snack Expo: https://snack.expo.io/@nicocodes/hello-textinput

(Ignore the fact that Web and iOS doesn't work for this example. I copied in only some sections of my app to show my issue on Android.)

**Would anyone have a solution for this?**

Comment: Can you share the component code?

Comment: @giotskhada Yes, I have updated my question with an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that the `Touchable` component is placed outside its parent view, and therefore doesn't respond to touches (since touches bubble down from the parent view).

You can either dynamically increase the height of the container view (the one that contains the input and the drop-down). You can use `LayoutAnimation` to animate this height increase using the native driver.

Or, you can use a very good library called `react-native-gesture-handler`. If you import your `Touchable`s from `react-native-gesture-handler`, they respond to touches even if they're outside of the parent view.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me get a bit further with fixing the issue

Comment: I faced with same issue and I used Touchables from "react-native-gesture-handeler". I'm able to touch the button but it also focus to TextInput. How did you solve that ?